# Replace media in media library

Tags: orchardcms

Is there any way to replace a file in the media library in orchard 1.9.x through the administrative UI? I can go into the file base and replace the files, but I am hoping to find a way that content editors can go in and replace a file using the same URL without having to delete the current file first.

Comment: Delete and re-upload? I don't think there's a way that's built-in. Maybe look in the gallery for a module.

Comment: Actually, since 1.9, media files are also referenced in database, so if you delete and re-upload, referenced items will be lost.

Comment: @urbanit is right. It wouldn't be that hard to write a custom action for this scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent pull request adressing the replace issue. You could download the changes recompile Orchard to get the replace functionality.

https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/7160